# body {Background-image: url(...) } семантика

Tags: html, css

Семантично ли задавать для `body {background-image: ...}`?

Картинка большая, и еще имеет отступ(в макете) сверху в `100 пикселей`.

В `body` картинку видно полностью, но если задать `main`, то видно кусок.

Comment: так обычно для слайдеров делают или для parallax , во всех остальных случаев лучше в отдельном фале

Answer (score 2):

Нежелательно так делать, лучше создайте обёртку необходимой картине и поставьте её на фон. Поверьте, легче управлять своим тегом чем `<body>`.
Просто создайте сткруктуру html наподобие такой:

```
<body>
    <div class='main-wrapper'>
       <div class='content-1'>
           <span> Мой контент 1 </span>
       </div>
       <div class='content-2'>
           <span> Мой контент 2 </span>
       </div>
       <div class='content-3'>
           <span> Мой контент 3 </span>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

И вместо `body` задайте фон для `.main-wrapper`:

```
.main-wrapper {
    background-image: url('somatic.jpg');
}
```